# Joystick won't work using SDL

Tags: events, sdl, joystick

I'm building a simple game in SDL. I've been through countless tutorials and I've clearly missed something as it still ignoring my Joystick completely

In my constructor

```
SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
```

In my update I'm calling a test to check I have actually initialized the joystick

```
if (SDL_NumJoysticks() <= 0)
{
done = true;
}
```

Here is my player update as well

```
void World::playerMovement()
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent (&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;
            case SDL_JOYAXISMOTION:
                if ( ( event.jaxis.value < -3200 ) || (event.jaxis.value > 3200 ) )
                {
                    test = true;
                }
                    break;
        }
   }
}
```

Test is simply a bool which once true will mean my enemies start spawning. I also run a check in main

```
if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK ) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    done = true;
}
```

When I run the game it loads as normal but no matter how much I move the joystick it won't set test to true.

I also tried using the following in the while poll event loop instead.

```
if (event.type == SDL_JOYAXISMOTION)
{
if(SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick, 1) > 0)
{
test = true;
}
}
```

Any idea's what I have missed?

Answer (score 3):

I found a weird behaviour in SDL2:

If no events are put into the queue, try adding the following before the SDL_Init call:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_JOYSTICK_ALLOW_BACKGROUND_EVENTS,"1");
```

Comment: Does this answer the OP's question? Perhaps you could edit your answer and expand on how this fit's into the OP's scenario?

Comment: Thank you!!! This was exactly my problem. I realized it's because I wasn't creating a window, only a console. So there was nothing to focus on. Allowing the capturing of background events fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think emartel has the best answer to make sure SDL_joystick is working.

When does World::playerMovement() happen?  The overall flow of your program is hard to determine from these snippets.

I'm happy to share with you my code for handling joysticks, which keeps track of: multiple joysticks, axes scaled [-1,1] with deadzone removed, and buttons held down.

- http://www.raptor007.com/code/RaptorEngine_Joystick.zip

And here's a snippet of how that would be utilized as part of your main loop:

```
// FIXME: SDL needs to be initialized before we get here.

JoystickManager Joy;
Joy.Initialize();
double deadzone = 0.02;

// Main loop.
bool done = false;
while( ! done )
{
    // Keep the list of joysticks up-to-date.
    Joy.FindJoysticks();

    // Handle all user input.
    SDL_Event event;
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
    {
        // Let the JoystickManager track events relevant to it.
        Joy.TrackEvent( &event );

        // FIXME: Handle single-press events here (next target, etc).
        // Don't handle button-held-down events like firing (see below).

        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            done = true;
    }

    // Read joystick 0 analog axes.
    double roll = Joy.Axis( 0, 0, deadzone );
    double pitch = Joy.Axis( 0, 1, deadzone );
    double yaw = Joy.Axis( 0, 3, deadzone );
    double throttle = Joy.AxisScaled( 0, 2, 1., 0., 0., deadzone );

    // Read joystick 0 buttons held down.
    bool firing = Joy.ButtonDown( 0, 0 );

    // FIXME: Update game objects and draw graphics.
}
```

Comment: @user2014680 Another thought; do you have two different loops that call SDL_PollEvent?  There should only be one, whether you use my code or not.  Each time you call SDL_PollEvent(&event) it gives you the event data _and removes it from the queue_.  So a second loop through SDL_PollEvent won't see events that were already removed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `joystick` points to a valid joystick?

You state that you're getting it in your `Constructor`... does that contructor happen to be called before you initialize SDL with `SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK`? This could happen if your player is a global variable.

Make sure that in order you:

- Init the Joystick subsystem, either by adding it to your `SDL_Init` with `| SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK` or by calling `SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);`
- Check `SDL_NumJoysticks() > 0`
- Get joystick 0: `joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);`
- Enable events: `SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);`
- Process your events with `SDL_PollEvent`
- At the end of your program, close your joystick: SDL_JoystickClose(joystick);

Also, make sure the joystick is properly detected in Windows and reports its inputs properly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SDL isn't init proper.

replace

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK)
```

with

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)
```

Comment: This was the issue for me on Windows 11. Weirdly, I did get some events, but only for two axes. Switching to `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING` gave me all axes, balls, buttons, and hats.

Answer (score 0):

Is this SDL 1.2 or 2.0? In my case, on 2.0 SDL_PollEvent(&event) didn't actually put any data in the event struct. After that call, I had to use SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick_id, axis) and friends to get data.

So in your case, try to move the SDL_JoystickGetAxis call out of the if-test on event-type.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `SDL_NumJoysticks` to get the number of controllers connected, then call `SDL_JoystickOpen` which returns a joystick identifier before your game loop then you will receive the `SDL_JOYAXISMOTION` events.

e.g.

```
int num_joy;
num_joy = SDL_NumJoysticks();
printf("%d joysticks found\n", num_joy);
for(int i = 0; i < num_joy; i++)
{
    SDL_Joystick *joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(i);
    printf("Joystick name: %s\n", SDL_JoystickName(joystick));
}

SDL_Event event;
bool quit = false;
// Game loop
while(!quit)
{
    // event loop
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_JOYAXISMOTION)
        {
            printf("Joystick______EVENT!\n");
        }
        // etc.....
```

See https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickName

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how this can help you, but I do know that pygame supports joystick. And pygame is the python port of the SDL library. If everything fails, I guess you can always write that particular piece of code in python.